# SQL Server: insert next available int

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, auto-increment

I'm dealing with a table in SQL Server that has a `serial_no` column, which is defined as a non null int. It doesn't appear to be an auto incrementing field, as if I leave that column out of my insert statement I get an error saying that the `serial_no` field cannot be null.

So how do I insert the next available number?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1 FROM mytable))
```

but I get an error saying that subqueries cannot be used in this context.

EDIT: This table is used in an off the shelf product so I cannot change the design and make the serial_no column an auto increment.

Comment: Does it have to be unique across all rows?? The recommended approaches in the answers typically aren't concurrency-safe, e.g. you could end up with duplicates..... you either need to a) make this an `INT IDENTITY` column and let SQL Server worry about it, b) do a lot more work than the obviuos `SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1`, or c) wait for SQL Server 2011 and use it's concept of `SEQUENCES`

Comment: marc_s, I totally agree, but unfortunately I can't change the DB design. What if I lock the table, do the insert and then unlock? Would that protect it from creating a dupe? Or would a query that's in waiting simply wait for the lock to release and then insert a duplicate # anyway?

Comment: Can you run a trace to determine how the 3rd party application creates the value and just do the same?  I would say that if there is not an identity column they are likely using a table to hold the next value.  There is an answer that mentions this technique already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can improve write concurrency with locking hints

```
INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no, value)
SELECT MAX (serial_no)+1, @value 
FROM mytable WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

If performance is't important, try TABLOCKX in place of ROWLOCK, XLOCK

However, given this isn't safe either you need to retry

```
DECLARE @retry bit
SET @retry = 1

WHILE @Retry = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no, value)
        SELECT MAX (serial_no)+1, @value 
        FROM mytable WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

        SET @Retry = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627  --PK violation
            RAISERROR ('blah', 16, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

**Or change to an IDENTITY column and do it properly...**

Comment: identity is the best choice when possible.  However, there are cases where a manually managed unique key is needed.  This happens to be the case I'm in now.  A client wants a unique FileNumber, that is sequential, user editable, and changes the beginning of the sequence every year

Comment: @George: we now have sequences in SQL Server 2012 fro this kind of stuff

Answer (score 2):

The error can be fixed by  dropping the VALUES

```
INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no, value)

SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1 ,
@value 
FROM mytable)
```

But this is a bad idea. There's a race condition on MAX(serial_no)+1 (e.g. two Inserts get the same value for Max(Serial_no).

You're better off using an auto increment field. You could also create a table that stores the current next value and increment it instead of using max.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the possibility of duplicates with this MAX()+1 approach; and suggesting the auto-increment solution

Comment: Problem is that it's not my table or application. I can't change it.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no) SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1 FROM mytable
```

Comment: not safe - could end up with duplicates, if two INSERT happen from two connections at almost the same time....

Answer (score -1):

Try it without VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (serial_no) SELECT MAX(serial_no)+1 FROM mytable
```

Comment: not safe - could end up with duplicates, if two INSERT happen from two connections at almost the same time....