# SELECT CASE to ExecuteScalar()

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, executescalar

I'm trying to insert new records into a table. The first field in the table is an supposed to be an autonumber, even though it isn't at the moment, and I am trying to run `ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve the `MAX` of that field (`ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID`, if it is NULL or 0, I would like to make it 1, else make it `MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) + 1`.

I am not really familiar with SQL all that well, and I've done my best to try and format it correctly but I can tell I am off on something.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID IS NULL OR MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) < 1
        THEN e.BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID = '1'
        ELSE MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) + 1
    END AS ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID
FROM ELECT_BONUS_DFRL AS e
GROUP BY e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef9a95/2) - It keeps saying there is an error at the `=` in my `THEN` statement.

Now, I thought about creating a variable like `@NextID` and using that to hold the value of 1 or the MAX + 1, but I'm not sure if that would interfere with my `ExecuteScalar()` in my program.

I also am not sure if it's allowed to assign values to the columns like that, and by that I mean: `THEN e.BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID = '1'`

The code in my program is :

```
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT MAX(BONUS_SEQ_ID) FROM ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID;"
    Dim maxCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    nextID = Convert.ToInt32(maxCmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

I am hoping `nextID` will hold the next number in the sequence.

Example:

```
+------------------+--------------+
|ELECT_BONUS_SEQ_ID|  Percentage  |
+------------------+--------------+
|        1         |      100     |
+------------------+--------------+
|     nextID       |              |  <- new record to insert
```

PS - If you're looking at the SQLFiddle and scratching your head at the Data types, all of the `varchar` fields will be encrypted data, and the guy who set up the DDL didn't make the `SEQ_ID` an `INT` & `IDENTITY` so it doesn't autoincrement. (this will be resolved in the future, I am hoping.)

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Also, if you care to shed some light as to why it wouldn't work for the ways I tried please do!

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are trying to do, Are you trying to retrieve the next available incrementing number ? so you can then use it in an insert ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Sorry I am somewhat bad at explaining things, haha.

Comment: in that case here is the answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853361/sql-server-insert-next-available-int

Comment: @AndrePageot I believe that is it. Thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to update the source data within a `SELECT` which is not possible.  Did you mean this?

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID IS NULL OR MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) < 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) + 1
    END AS ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID
FROM ELECT_BONUS_DFRL AS e
GROUP BY e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID;
```

If you are trying to update the source data then you need to do the UPDATE in one statement and the SELECT in another.

Comment: I think your first sentence sums up what I was trying to do. Damn. Know any work-arounds? The problem is that I am not trying to UPDATE, per se, I am trying to hold a value to use in a query. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Newbie then will the query I posted work?  Also be aware that `ExecuteScalar` only returns _one value_  if you're grouping by `ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID` then you may get multiple values back and any values after the first one will be ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure what your query does, exactly. So if it's Null or < 1 then 1. What is the `THEN 1` doing here? It means it's true, correct? If that's the case then what is the `ELSE` doing?

Comment: If the condition is true that column value will be `1`, otherwise it will be `MAX(e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID) + 1`

Comment: I just realized that you're calling `MAX` on a column but grouping by that column, which doesn't seem right.  Do you need the `GROUP BY`?  Or do you need to group on a different column?

Comment: So, that's exactly what I was trying to do. The problem is, nothing is returned when the query is ran (even though it is executed). I expected to see a '1' under `e.ELECT_BONUS_DFRL_SEQ_ID` but I got nothing.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` was required by SQL I believe

Comment: You should be able to leave it off. It will just find the max of all records.